# Drawing app - the easiest design

Tags: wpf, canvas, inkcanvas

Well, I'm a newbie. I'd like to write an app in WPF. The main purpouse will be in drawing predefined elements/objects. Input from user is mostly realized by text boxes - numbers. But I'd like to add some kind of user input into drawing itself too + zooming and moving. Next functionality will be in saving the draw for later loading and another editing (printing maybe, but it's far far away).

I can imagine something like this:

- due to some user interaction I'd prefere to use of InkCanvas
- i want to define my own elements/objects with some properties. But where it will be define? Some external file maybe?
- the save file will be composed of XAML code only

I will study this more lately, but I want to know if my thoughts are in the right way.

Are these points correct, or completely bullshit? :)

Thanks, and sorry for English...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what are you looking for, but here a little list of advice to help you on reaching your goal:

- First of all, if you are crating an application, you should see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx) before. It explain the Model-View-ViewModel pattern, which is essential when you are creating something on WPF. This can help you abount your 2nd point.
- Regarding your save file, i don't know exactly what you have in mind, but it depends on what do you want to save exactly. If you want, InkCanvas have the option to export directly the work in a [bitmap](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ba4dc89f-0169-43a9-8374-68e1fb34a222/saving-inkcanvas-as-image?forum=wpf) . If you need to store some setting, depending on your need you can work with [Settings](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25829/User-Settings-Applied) or [Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/resources-wpf)
- InkCanvas seems the appropriate tool for your need. Of course you will have to build your app around this control